# Python Import error: undefined symbol: _Z33parallel_pthreads_set_threads_numi

Tags: opencv, python-3.x, image-processing, python-3.4, opencv3.0

I am trying to compile and install OpenCV3(targeting Python3.4) on CentOS6.
When I cmake, I set the following options.

```
BUILD_opencv_python3=ON
BUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF(turned this off because I am not using the video modules and this throws some errors while compiling)
PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/python/bin/python3.4
PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/python/include/python3.4m
PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/local/python/lib/python3.4
PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include
PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

With the configuration above, compliation goes fine, but when I try to import an output file(`cv2.cpython-34m.so`), I get the following error.

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov  2 2015, 17:44:31) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2(←renamed from cv2.cpython-34m.so to this)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/dai/opencv-3.0.0/build/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0: undefined symbol: _Z33parallel_pthreads_set_threads_numi
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your file `cv2.cpython-34m.so` could be change to `cv2.cpython-34m.py` in-order to import. That's just a suggestion.